# google-services.json throwing malformed exception

Tags: android, json, google-signin

Recently, I've added the Google Sign In function into my app, Google gave me a 'google-services.json' file to put into my app folder...

When I try to run, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
```

If I run again, it runs normally and the app works fine...

Here is my google-services.json file (got to hide some info):

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "Hidden",
    "project_id": "Hidden"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "Hidden",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "Hidden"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "Hidden",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "Hidden",
            "certificate_hash": "Hidden"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "Hidden",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "Hidden"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed??

At least, I want to hide the error message using that "JsonReader.setLenient(true)", but I don't know where I have to put it...

**----- EDIT -----**

I was not using revokeAccess() method into my activity, it seems to be necessary...

I've just added this method into my activity and now I'm not receiving any error messages

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after i received the google-services `Json` file from another person in txt format, when i copied the file as is it throw the exception above.

What i did is created manually `Json` file in android studio and copied the content from the txt file, and it compiled.